# how to create a Custom Form Field Type for Symfony2 which store a float,float?

Tags: symfony

I need hekp to create a Custom Form Field Type for a Input which looks like:

```
"float, float"
```

I store it as a string in the database but the form input MUST be "float, float"

I dont know how to make this, I tried to look into the documentation here:
http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/create_custom_field_type.html

but I did not solve it

Comment: "float, float" is a string. do you mean you need to validate that the string contains two floats separated by a comma? If that's the case you'll just need to write your own validator and not worry about data transformers.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think what you want rather than a custom field type is a [custom validator](http://symfony.com/doc/current/cookbook/validation/custom_constraint.html) in combination with a [data transformer](http://symfony.com/doc/2.0/cookbook/form/data_transformers.html) which transforms your string input prior to validation.